# Intellisense not working if View has the name "_Layout"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense

Currently I have a bug in my ASP.NET mvc5 project (Visual Studio 2013).

If my layout view ("placed at Views\Shared\") is named "_Layout.cshtml" then intellisense is not working as expected (eg: it doesn't see missing references)

If my layout is named otherwise than "_Layout.cshtml" eg: "_Layout2.cshtml" everything works fine as expected...

Any solutions? Thank you

Comment: Unclear. Which _Layout are you talking about? The one in `\Shared` ?

Comment: Yes the layout placed in \Shared folder